# one word to describe tarnished beauty

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Need one word to describe "tarnished beauty", or "beauty in imperfection". Need it to sound arty and quirky as its for name of a plausible studio. Words in other languages are welcome. Don't want it to sound ordinary.

Comment: As a name for a business or studio, why not consider proper names from antiquity or literature that evoke the wistful appreciation of a flawed or decaying glory. My first thought was 'Ozymandias' but that's not quite right - have a look at the works of the Romantic poets and artists,

Comment: _Vetus Venustas_ (Latin) loosely translates as The old charm or old beauty.

Comment: Thank you.. wIll check out the works like you suggested!

Comment: Do you mean a gone beauty as in "splendors of the past" or "former glory" or do you rather refer to something imperfect, but with a lot of charm ? May you precise the type of studio ? music, shooting, game ...

Comment: With a single word, let's say "unforgettable" (I don't know whether it fits or not), you would probably face intellectual property rights.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the word **Patina**?

Comment: I did think of it but Patina alone doesn't have the quality of being the name of the studio. Maybe if it is used in a catchy phrase..

Comment: The emphasis is on both. Beauty that is imperfect/tarnished/aged

Comment: "The metal developed a rich patina with age."  Whether it's an "arty" and "quirky" name for *any* studio, let alone a "plausible" studio, is a matter of opinion. It has a patina of plausibility in my opinion.

Comment: Sounds like a good name for a studio to me- especially one that features bronze sculpture.  "Wow that's a great piece. Where'd you get it?" "I found it at Patina last week.  They've got a new artist in now-  Al Cuprum."

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I like 'patina', because it suggests desirability, which 'tarnished', with its negative connotation, does not.